# Pentaho Windows | Increase RAM is not getting applied

Tags: pentaho

### I have pentaho 8.3 and 8.2 Community.

In Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019, when I increase the RAM https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.2/0H0/070/020/010 it does not get applied and it still takes a lot of time to Start the Application.

Works fine in Linux.

Comment: have you tried turn it off and on again?

Comment: What version of PDI are you using ? Just increasing the memory won't make it start faster, this is not a hardware issue. Depending on the version there are different ways to handle it.

Comment: PDIs snail like crawl during startup is mostly due to the plugins that are included as standard. You can remove quite a few of them if you don't need them.

Comment: I did restart the app, ok i'll try that out (also i have issue only on windows bases system, in linux its smooth)

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the designated memory on spoon.bat ?

- Xms: set initial Java heap size.
- Xmx: set the maximum Java heap size.
- XX:MaxPermSize: set size for Permanent Generation.

example: [PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbHTN.png)

PS: if you want better start up times check this :
[Improving startup time of Pentaho Data Integration](https://blog.twineworks.com/improving-startup-time-of-pentaho-data-integration-78d0803c559b)